# MySQL SELECT return wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, virtual-column

I'm working with MySQL 5.7. I created a table with a virtual column (not stored) of type DATETIME with an index on it. While I was working on it, I noticed that order by was not returning all the data (some data I was expecting at the top was missing). Also the results from MAX and MIN were wrong.
After I run

```
ANALYZE TABLE 
CHECK TABLE
OPTIMIZE TABLE
```

then the results were correct. I guess there was an issue with the index data, so I have few questions:

1. When and why this could happen?
2. Is there a way to prevent this?
3. among the 3 command I run, which is the correct one to use?

I'm worried that this could happen in the future but I'll not notice.

**EDIT**:

as requested in the comments I added the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_expired` tinyint(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(json_contains(`status`,'true','$.expired'),false)) VIRTUAL COMMENT 'used for index: it checks if status contains expired=true',
  `lifetime` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `expiration` datetime GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`create_date` + interval `lifetime` day)) VIRTUAL,
  `last_update` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `expiration` (`status_expired`,`expiration`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `ts_competition_item_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `ts_user_core` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1312459 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

Queries that were returning the wrong results:

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY expiration DESC;
SELECT max(expiration),min(expiration) FROM items;
```

Thanks

Comment: show your  schema , sample data and expected result

Comment: someone is playing with fire: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes-virtual-columns.html

Comment: why are you saying this?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the queries that return the wrong values.  We need to see the indexes, engine, specific 'virtual' declaration, etc.

Comment: Gonna need the query too!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you create a composite key on the virtual columns instead of two regular secondary indexes?

Answer (score 9):

### TLDR;

The trouble is that your data comes from virtual columns materialized via indexes. The check, optimize, analyze operations you are doing forces the indexes to be synced and fixes any errors. That gives you the correct results henceforth. At least until the index gets out of sync again.

### Why it may happen

Much of the problems are caused by issues with your table design. Let's start with.

```
`status_expired` tinyint(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ifnull(json_contains(`status`,'true','$.expired'),false)) VIRTUAL
```

No doubt this is created to overcome the fact that you cannot directly index a `JSON` column in mysql. You have created a virtual column and indexed that instead. It's all very well, but this column can hold only one of two values; `true` or `false`. Which means it has very poor cadinality. As a result, mysql is unlikely to use this index for anything.

But we can see that you have combined the `status_expired` column with the `expired` column when creating the index. Perhaps with the idea of overcoming this poor cardinality mentioned above. But wait...

```
`expiration` datetime GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`create_date` + interval `lifetime` day)) VIRTUAL,
```

Expiration is another virtual column. This has some repercussions.

> When a secondary index is created on a generated virtual column,
>   generated column values are materialized in the records of the index.
>   If the index is a covering index (one that includes all the columns
>   retrieved by a query), generated column values are retrieved from
>   materialized values in the index structure instead of computed “on the
>   fly”.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html#json-column-indirect-index

This is contrary to

> VIRTUAL: Column values are not stored, but are evaluated when rows are
>   read, immediately after any BEFORE triggers. A virtual column takes no
>   storage.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

We create virtual columns based on the sound principal that values generated by simple operations on columns shouldn't be stored to avoid redundancy, but by creating an index on it, we reintroduce redundancy.

### Proposed fixes

based on the information provided, you don't really seem to need the `status_expired` column or even the `expired` column. An item that's past it's expiry date is expired!

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `expire_date` datetime GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`create_date` + interval `lifetime` day)) VIRTUAL,
  `last_update` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `create_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `expiration` (`expired_date`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `ts_competition_item_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `ts_user_core` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1312459 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

Simply compare the current date with the expired_date column in the above table when you need to find out which items have expired. The difference here is instead of `expired` being a calculated item in every query, you calculate the `expiry_date` once, when you create the record.

This makes your table a lot neater and queries possibly faster

Comment: Thank you very much, but this is not actually explaining why the index corruption may happen. Few notes: 1. indexing virtual column is a suggestion from MySQL doc, it's a good practice 2. status_expired is used to speed up a different query (sorry I couldn't share all the details, so you couldn't know) 3. Any virtual column can be replaced with application logic, but they are useful, that's the reason I'm using expiration as virtual column